# How to Convince Programming Team to Let Go of Old Ways?

Tags: flat-file, relational, basic

This is more of a business-oriented programming question that I can't seem to figure out how to resolve.  I work with a team of programmers who have been working with BASIC for over 20 years.  I was brought in to help write the same software in .NET, only with updates and modern practices.  The problem is that I can't seem to get any of the other 3 team members(all BASIC programmers, though one does .NET now as well) to understand how to correctly do a relational database.  Here's the thing they won't understand:

We basically have a transaction that keeps track of a customer's tag information.  We need to be able to track current transactions and past transactions.  In the old system, a flat-file database was used that had one table that contained records with the basic current transaction of the customer, and another transaction that contained all the previous transactions of the customer along with important money information.  To prevent redundancy, they would overwrite the current transaction with the history transactions-(the history file was updated first, then the current one.)  It's totally unneccessary since you only need one transaction table, but my supervisor or any of my other two co-workers can't seem to understand this.  How exactly can I convince them to see the light so that we won't have to do ridiculous amounts of work and end up hitting the datatabse too many times?  Thanks for the input!

Comment: I have not altogether different problems myself, perhaps the answers here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369876/fighting-the-system-colleague-woes

Comment: But you can't teach an old dog new tricks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly I must admit it's not absolutely clear to me from your description what the data structures and logic flows in the existing structures actually are.  This does imply to me that perhaps you are not making yourself clear to your co-workers either, so one of your priorities must be to be able explain, either verbally or preferably in writing and diagrams, the current situation and the proposed replacement.  Please take this as an observation rather than any criticism of your question.

Secondly I do find it quite remarkable that programmers of 20 years experience do not understand relational databases and transactions.  Flat file coding went out of the mainstream a very long time ago - I first handled relational databases in a commercial setting back in 1988 and they were pretty commonplace by the mid-90s.  What sector and product type are you working on?  It sounds possible to me that you might be dealing with some sort of embedded or otherwise 'unusual' system, in which case you do need to make sure that you don't have some sort of communication issue and you're overlooking a large elephant that hasn't been pointed out to you - you wouldn't be the first 'consultant' brought into a team who has been set up in some manner by not being fed the appropriate information.  That said such archaic shops do still exist - one of my current clients systems interfaces to a flat-file based system coded in COBOL, and yes, it is hell to manage ;-)

Finally, if you are completely sure of your ground and you are faced with a team who won't take on board your recommendations - and demonstration code is a good idea if you can spare the time -then you'll probably have to accept the decision gracefully and move one.  Myself in this position I would attempt to abstract out the issue - can the database updates be moved into stored procedures for example so the code to update both tables is in the SP and can be modified at a later date to move to your schema without a corresponding application change?  Make sure your arguments are well documented and recorded so you can revisit them later should the opportunity arise.

You will not be the first coder who's had to implement a sub-optimal solution because of office politics - use it as a learning experience for your own personal development about handling such situations and commiserate yourself with the thought you'll get paid for the additional work.  Often the deciding factor in such arguments is not the logic, but the 'weight of reputation' you yourself bring to the table - it sounds like having been brought in you don't have much of that sort of leverage with your team, so you may have to work on gaining a reputation by exceling at implementing what they do agree to do before you have sufficient reputation in subsequent cases - you need to be modded up first!

Comment: Thanks.  This is very insightful.  And I'm sorry my descriptions are somewhat vague, but I can't be too specific for security reasons.  And I am sure this is the right way to go.  My brother, who used to work here believed the same thing and the department still wouldn't accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you can't.

If you read some XP books, they often say that one of your biggest hurdles will be convincing your team to abandon what they have always done.

Generally they will recommend letting people who can't adapt go to other projects (Or just letting them go).

Code reviews might help in your case.  Mandatory code reviews of every line of code is not unheard of.

Answer (score 4):

Sometime the best argument is an example.  I'd write a prototype (or a replacement if not too much work).  With an example to examine it will be easier to see the pros and cons of a relational database.

As an aside, flat-file databases have their places since they are so much easier to "administer" than a true relational database.  Keep an open mind.  ;-)

Comment: Show, don't tell, in concrete form.  There's nothing better than proving you're right.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may have to lead by example - when people see that the "new" way is less work they will adopt it (as long as you don't rub their noses in it).

I would also ask yourself whether the old design is actually causing a problem or whether it is just aesthetically annoying. It's important to pick your battles - if the old design isn't causing a performance problem or making the system hard to maintain you may want to leave the old design alone.

Finally, if you do leave the old design in place, try and abstract the interface between your new code and the old database so if you do persuade your co-workers to improve the design later you can drop the new schema in without having to change anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to extract a whole lot except general frustration from the original question.

Yes, there are a lot of techniques and habits long-timers pick up over time that can be useless and even costly in light of technology changes.  Some things that made sense when  processing power, memory, and even disk was expensive can be foolish attempts at optimization now.  It is also very much the case that people accumulate bad habits and bad programming patterns over time.

You have to be careful though.

Sometimes there are good reasons for the things those old timers do.  Sadly, they may not even be able to verbalize the "why" - if they even know why anymore.

I see a lot of this sort of frustration when newbies come into an enterprise software development shop.  It can be bad even when the environment is all fairly modern technology and tools.  If most of your experience is in writing small-community desktop and Web applications a lot of what you "know" may be wrong.

Often there are requirements for transaction journaling at a level above what your DBMS may do.  Quite often it can be necessary to go beyond DB transaction semantics in order to ensure time-sequence correctness, once and only once updating, resiliancy, and non-repudiation.

And this doesn't even begin to address the issues involved in enterprise or inter-enterprise scalability.  When you begin to approach half a million complex transactions a day you will find that RDBMS technology fails you.  Because relational databases are not designed to handle high transaction volumes you must often break with standard paradigms for normalization and updating.  Conventional RDBMS locking techniques can destroy scalability no matter how much hardware you throw at the problem.

It is easy to dismiss all of it as stodginess or general wrong-headedness - even incompetence.  But be careful because this isn't always the case.

And by the way:  There are other models besides the RDBMS, and the alternative to an RDBMS is not necessarily "flat files" - contrary to the experience of of most coders today.  There are transactional hierarchical DBMSs that can handle much higher throughput than an RDBMS.  [IMS](http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/mainframe/marchapril09/trends/24577printp1.aspx) is still very much alive in large IBM shops, for example.  Other vendors offer similar software for different platforms.

Of course in a 4-man shop maybe none of this applies.

Answer (score 0):

Sign them up for some decent trainings and then it's up to you to convince them that with new technologies a lot more is possible (or at least easier!).

But I think the most important thing here is that professional, certified trainers teach them the basics first. They will be more impressed by that instead of just one of their colleagues telling them: "hey, why not use this?"

Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422076/subtly-tell-someone-that-you-cant-just-teach-them-and-them-trying-to-help-me-is).

Answer (score 0):

The following may not apply in yr situation, but you make very little mention of technical details, so I thought I'd mention it...

Sometimes, if the access patterns are very different for current data than for historical data (I'm making this example up, but say that Current data is accessed 1000s of times per second, and accesses a small subset of columns, and all current data fits in less than 1 GB, whereas, say, historical data uses 1000s of GBs, is accessed only 100s of times per day, and access is to all columns),

then, what your co-workers are doing would make perfect sense, for performance optimization. By separating the current data (albiet redundantly) you can optimize the indices and data structures in that table, for the higher frequency access paterns that you could not do in the historical table.

Not everything that is "academically", or "technically" correct from a purely relational perspective makes sense when applied in an actual practical situation.